# Codeigniter for newbie : Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Im using mac and XAMPP as the bundler. I'm a beginner to the CI3 Framework.
I dont even know how to fix this error, pls help me.

> Warning: require_once(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ci-app-v3/system/core/CodeIgniter.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ci-app-v3/index.php on line 315
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ci-app-v3/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php') in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ci-app-v3/index.php on line 315

Comment: Permission denied. That means whatever user the server is running as isn’t allowed to read that file. To fix it, you need to grant permission to that directory and or file for that user. (I don’t know how to do it on Mac, sorry)

Comment: i already tried to grant the access for the file with "Get Info" but it wont do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Open Acces on folder ci-app-v3, on Macbook you can click right on mouse than click "Get Info" than go to "Sharing and Permissions" add "Read and Write" Privilege to user everyone. After that click configuration than choose "Apply to enclosed items"

it work for me